# Convert a string to a double - is this possible?

Tags: php

Just wondering in php, if it was possible to convert a string to a double. I am using a financial web service which provides a price as a string. I really need to process this as a double and was wondering how i would convert it

thanks

Comment: **Don't use floating point for monetary transaction code.**

Comment: what should i do with it then?

Comment: Integers. Use cents or finer units.

Comment: KennyTM sums it up correctly.  Some of the reasons you do this are so that floating point inaccuracies don't cause unexpected problems (numbers that look identical but are not, inaccuracies growing in magnitude over time due to impricise internal representation, etc.)

Comment: @Beska Like in Office Space? :)

Comment: @Kulingar, like in Superman 3 ;)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Just use [**`floatval()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php).

E.g.:

```
$var = '122.34343';
$float_value_of_var = floatval($var);
echo $float_value_of_var; // 122.34343
```

And in case you wonder [`doubleval()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval.php) is just an alias for `floatval()`.

And as the other say, in a financial application, float values are critical as these are not precise enough. E.g. adding two floats could result in something like `12.30000000001` and this error could propagate.

Comment: Works great in 5.4 and disables string + string warnings in IDE

Answer (score 24):

For arbitrary precision mathematics PHP offers the Binary Calculator which supports numbers of any size and precision, represented as strings.

```
$s = '1234.13';
$double = bcadd($s,'0',2);
```

[PHP: bcadd](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bcadd.php)

Comment: 20 years of working with PHP and still learning new cool functions! +1!

Comment: What about transform the string to double?

Answer (score 5):

Use `doubleval()`. But be very careful about using decimals in financial transactions, and validate that user input **very** carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Why is floatval the best option for financial comparison data? bc functions only accurately turn strings into real numbers.