# How to convert a "decimal string" into an integer without the period in PHP

Tags: php, html, math, numbers

If I have, say, `8.1` saved as a string/plaintext, how can I change that into the integer (that I can do addition with) `81`? (I've got to remove the period and change it into an integer. I can't seem to figure it out even though I know it should be simple. Everything I try simply outputs `1`.)

Comment: `str_replace` and then casting using `(int)`.

Comment: If you're always sure that it has the pattern x.x (one digit before and one digit after the period) you can simply multiply it with 10.

Comment: @Michael No. That's not accurate.

Comment: @phant0m - I'm always interested in corrections. But if the source data always comes in this pattern: x.x (like 1.0 / 2.7 / 7.9 / 9.9) and the result should be in this pattern: xx (like 10, 27, 79, 99) - the multiplication with 10 would be sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also try this

```
$str = '8.1';
$int = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
echo $int; // 81
echo $int+1; // 82
```

[**DEMO.**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QwJCkR)

Answer (score 2):

If you're dealing with whole numbers (as you said), you could use the `intval` function that is built into PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

So basically, once you have your string parsed and setup as a whole number you can do something like:

`intval("81");`

And get back the integer 81.

Example:

```
$strNum = "81";
$intNum = intval($strNum);
echo $intNum;
// "81"
echo getType($intNum);
// "integer"
```

Comment: But he's not dealing with whole numbers, as he said, but with numbers of the form `8.1`!

Answer (score 1):

Since php does auto-casting, this should work:

```
<?php

$str="8432.145522";
$val = str_replace('.','', $str);
print $str." : ".$val;

?>
```

Output:

```
8432.145522 : 8432145522
```

Comment: How is this related to auto-casting?

Comment: After removing the period the result is a string with a so-to-say integer number. In PHP there is no need to cast it explicitly to an int when the variable is used in a calculation. This second step (the calculation) is not contained in my answer.
To explicitly validate if the string contains an int the use of intval is recommended (but not needed for the first step: simply removing the period from the string).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work. But if you always have something.something,(like 1.1 or 4.2), you can multiply by 10 and do intval('string here'). But if you have something.somethingsomething or with more somethings(like 1.42 and 5.234267, etc.), I don't know what to say. Maybe a function to keep multiplying by ten until it's an integer with is_int()?

Sources:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php
- [Convert a string to a double - is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540078/convert-a-string-to-a-double-is-this-possible)

Comment: I think it would be easier to multiply by 100.  That should move the decimal over and guarantee a whole number in 1 operation.

Comment: But what if the number is 5.5, @mariozig ? The number would be 50! D:

Comment: You're right. I was thinking in the context of money and assuming he just wanted to convert a decimal to the number of pennies it represented! :X

Comment: No! Floats are not accurate, this is *not* the correct thing to do.