# Change from string to variable

Tags: php

[image]

Hi Guys , just need a tiny help here . the green numbers on the right are strings . how do I change them to numbers  ? Additionally I also need them to be 2 decimal place. What function do I use?? I tried the method below but the output was 0. Answers all welcome.

```
$profitText = $profitText*1;
$profitText = (float)$profitText;
round($profitText,2); 
number_format($profitText, 2);
```

**EDITED**
Okay guys the deriving of this variable is really complex. every step has its functional purpose but heres the derivation. After the last profitText at the bottom, I realised this is now a string. why is that so? and how do I fix it?

```
 $offeropen=$row['offerprice'];//1.3334
      $pips=$offerpricepl-$offeropen;//difference btw prices , eg. 0.0023
      $closedb=$offerpricepl;// nothing
      $pips1=round($pips, 6);// round to 6 decimal points
      $pips2 = str_replace('.', '', $pips1);// remove decimal
        if ($pips2<0)
      {
        $pips2 = str_replace('-', '', $pips2);// methodology for adjusting figures and negative values back
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');
        $pips2 = -1 * abs($pips2);
      }
      else {
        $pips2 = ltrim($pips2, '0');// for triming 0 on the left
      }
      $pips3=$pips2/$minipipskiller;// methodology
    $ticksize= "0.0001";// FOR PROFIT AND LOSS
      $lot1 = "100000";
      $sizecalc=$row['size'] * $lot1;

        if ($row['type']=="buy")
      { 
        $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
      }
      if ($row['type']=="sell")
      {
        $profitandloss=$sizecalc*$ticksize*$pips3; //per TRADE
      }

      $zero= '0';

      if($profitandloss<$zero) {
            $profitText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
        } elseif ($profitandloss>$zero) {
            $profitText = "<div style=\"color: green;\">$profitandloss</div>";
        }
        // for profit and loss counting

        $profitText=ltrim($profitText,'0');
```

Comment: You don't necessarily need to convert them to numbers - if you're using a string where a number is expected, it'll convert it to a number for you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: take a look at this.....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540078/convert-a-string-to-a-double-is-this-possible

Comment: Try casting with (float)$numbemVar or read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: ***before*** you change the variable, what does `var_dump($profitText)` give? (please from view source in your browser, not from the HTML page)

Comment: after using code it becomes float 0

Comment: view source in the browser. then tell use about the string with 37 characters each which those 37 exactly are. May guess is simple: You have HTML strings there. PHP can convert them to numbers and correctly does so: 0. Number zero. They start with `<`. So you now see that you are asking the wrong question? You perhaps are more interested to read: [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/367456)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$profitText = "<div style=\"color: red;\">$profitandloss</div>";
```

You're trying to turn `$profitText` into a number. It's actually a string of HTML, and PHP can't manage to work out what it's supposed to do with it, so when you cast it to a number, it's returning 0.

Solution:

Use `$profitandloss` instead

Comment: Well, that looks like it's where the content for that column is coming from, so I assume it's the actual number you're working with, rather than a formatted version.

Comment: This is what im looking , thanks man! i checked var dump , yes it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
floatval(mixed var)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

```
$profit = round(floatval(trim($profitText)), 2);
```

Proof: http://codepad.org/jFTqhUIk

Comment: what do you mean by the string is valid?

Comment: Specifically i'd wonder if there's blank space before or after the value.  Try using ltrim and rtrim on the string to make sure its "clean" before attempting to cast it.  EDIT: seems this is accounted for in the answer given.

Comment: @nigel - could you edit your question to include the code where you define your variables?

Comment: @user2366842 Well, trim() combines ´ltrim()´ and ´rtrim()´

Answer (score 1):

this will do both requested points together:

`$floatProfitVar = number_format($profit, 2, '.');`

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) or `printf` and has been designed for exactly that job:

```
printf('%.2F', '1.8'); # prints "1.80"
```

Demo: https://eval.in/44078

You can use string input for the float number parameter (F = float, locale independent) as well as integer or float input. PHP is loosely typed.

Use `sprintf` if you want to get back a string, `printf` prints directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = intval(floatval($profitText)*100)/100.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this `$profitText = $profitText*1;` would work unless you first do `$profitText = (float)$profitText;`. Remember that you have to convert the string first before you can do any manipulation.

floatval(mixed $var) can also be used instead of typecasting but typecasting should work fine