# How to convert string to integer or double in php?

Tags: php

I have two string : `'99.00'` and `'99.154'`,
I would like to convert `'99.00'` to `99` and `'99.154'` to `99.154`
How can I do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a string to a number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529656/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-a-number-in-php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string to a double - is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540078/convert-a-string-to-a-double-is-this-possible)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has two build-in functions for that.

If you want to convert **String -> Integer**, you can/should use:

```
<?php
echo intval('90.00'); //returns 99
?>
```

If you want do dig deeper, i will Link you both Docs at the bottom.

But.. if you want to convert **String -> Double**, you can/should use:

```
<?php
echo floatval('90.154'); //returns 90.154
?>
```

In additon to **floatval** you can use **doubleval**, its an alias for floatval

And here the Links:
[intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.intval.php)
[floatval()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.floatval.php)
[doubleval()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.doubleval.php)

Comment: How to I determine when use intval or floatval ?, because value from a string array.

Comment: You could check if it is an integer with the following build-in function.
`is_int(*YOUR_VALUE*)`. This Function returns true or false.